# Why is there a delay when blurring in CKEDITOR and can I get around it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, ckeditor

I'm trying to add a class to my body tag when I focus on an input, textarea, or CKeditor instance.  And remove the class when I blur from any of these.  The problem is that when I blur from a CKeditor instance and immediately focus on an input or textarea, the focus event happens before the blur event does.  There is a significant delay when blurring from a CKeditor instance.  I've tried using delay() and setTimeout() in addition to many other things and I can't get it to work.  Since it's blurring after I focus, the focus event is adding the class to the body and then the blur event is removing the class.

I'm doing this because I need to reposition the header and hide the footer when the user is on a mobile device the keyboard displays.  Below is the code I current have.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get around this?  Thanks!

```
 if ($("html").hasClass("touch")) {

 // Set focus and blur listeners for all editors to be created.  
 CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function() {

      var editor = txtEditor.get_instance();      

      editor.on('focus', function(e) {
      $("body").addClass(fix);
      });

      editor.on('blur', function(e) {
      $("body").removeClass(fix);
      });
    });

    $("input").on("focus", function(e) {
      $("body").addClass(fix);  
    })
    .on("blur", function(e) {
      $("body").removeClass(fix);
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The delay is caused by the [focus manager](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.focusManager). It waits [200ms](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/focusmanager.js#L72) for the next editor UI component to receive focus. It has to do wait, because in various cases and depending on browsers focus may be moved from one component (e.g. editable element) to another component (toolbar, elements path, dialog) with a significant delay. I know from my own experience that it can even exceed 100ms. If it wasn't waiting the [`editor#blur`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-blur) and [`editor#focus`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-focus) events would be fired many times when working within editor.

In your case, the input element should behave like editor's UI component. If it gets focus the same should happen as when editor gets focus and vice versa. I think that the easiest solution is to register it as editor's UI component:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function() {
    var editor = txtEditor.get_instance();

    editor.focusManager.add(new CKEDITOR.dom.element(inputEl));

    editor.on('focus', function(e) {
        $("body").addClass(fix);
    });

    editor.on('blur', function(e) {
        $("body").removeClass(fix);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback, but I got it.  I was able to place an editor.focusManager.forceBlur() statement in the focus statement of my input fields.  That way the blur from any previous ckeditors is immediate.  Thanks again though!

Jesse